# Citing with Jabref - don't print (n.d.) if no editor is given

Tags: biblatex, citing, jabref

I would like to cite a website using biblatex and jabref.
That's the JabRef Code

```
@Misc{BZ2020,
  author  = {{Bundeszentrale für politische Bildung}},
  url     = {https://www.bpb.de/nachschlagen/lexika/lexikon-der-wirtschaft/19363/fusion},
  urldate = {2020-06-04},
}
```

I would like to get: Author (Date), https in the bibliography.
Unfortunately I get: Author (n.d.) ...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\space}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

Comment: "n.d." is added if no year/date is given. The editor field should have nothing to do with it and can be left empty.

Comment: If and how this can be resolved depends on the bibliography style and other settings you use. Would it be possible to post a short example document and an example `.bib` entry that show your current bibliography setup and the output you get (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)

Comment: Thanks for your quick Reply! I have inserted a date in "Date" and "Urldate". Is there another field that needs an entry?

Comment: No. Both `date` and `urldate` are usually taken into account for `labeldate` calculations and will result in a year being shown instead of "n.d.". I'm afraid you will have to post an example document that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Misc{BZ2020,
  author       = {{Bundeszentrale für politische Bildung}},
  date         = {04.06.2020},
  title        = {Fusion},
  organization = {Bundeszentrale für politische Bildung},
  url          = {https://www.bpb.de/nachschlagen/lexika/lexikon-der-wirtschaft/19363/fusion},
  urldate      = {2020-06-04},
} 

That's the JabRef entry. \usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

Comment: Please edit that entry into your question (where it will be much easier to read). Please consider posting *fully compilable* code (see my two links above), so people can see exactly what you see - that avoids misunderstandings.

Comment: The standard styles will make that read "Bundeszentrale für politische Bildung (2020). Fusion. Bundeszentrale für politische Bildung. url: https://www.bpb.de/nachschlagen/lexika/lexikon-der-wirtschaft/19363/fusion (visited on 04/06/2020).", so you must be using a non-standard style. Can you please add a short document that shows how you cite that entry?

Comment: … thank you I'll try. Already failing to post a Question.

Comment: Maybe it is easier when I tell you what I would like to get. 
I would like to get a bibliography entry that Looks like that: 

Author (Date), https: 

That's it...

Comment: It won't help with the general question, but here it would probably be easier to go to a library and cite the Duden entry that the BpB copied directly (Duden Wirtschaft von A bis Z: Grundlagenwissen für Schule und Studium, Beruf und Alltag. 6. Aufl. Mannheim: Bibliographisches Institut 2016.).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is only realistic to help you get the result you want if one knows how you currently produce your bibliography. There are *many* different ways of producing bibliographies in LaTeX and many different styles. You'd probably not be too happy about a solution that requires you to change lots of code in your document. So a good solution (i.e. one that requires little changes) requires knowledge about the status quo. I realise that this means some work for you, but I'm sure it will pay off in the form of a beautiful bibliography.

Comment: Well. That Kind of solved my problem :D I just though that it could have to do with the command \parencite{} ?Maybe I give up on that one ans just take the book entry...thanks anyway

Comment: The example document I'm asking about would roughly look like this: https://gist.github.com/moewew/4588b7ba53d674e038951e43c1c3d219, just edit it to show your bibliography style and setup and you're good.

Comment: I just started to use JabRef and I am probably not aware of all funktions. All I use is one package, one style and then print bibliography. I cite with \parencite. Thats Pretty much everything I know About it...

Comment: Ah, that's all we need to know for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading `style=apa,` which produces citations and bibliographies according to the *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association*. The APA manual contains extremely detailed style requirements, amongst them is to show "n.d." if a citation does not have a date.

If you don't want APA style it may be better to use different, more generic style such as `style=authoryear,` or one of its derivatives.

While the standard styles will take `urldate` into account when they calculate the label date, APA style does not and will show "n.d." if there is only a `urldate`.

---

In this particular case you could try and add a `date` field. From the contents of the linked page `date={2016},` would seem sensible, since the entry is a copy of a dictionary entry from 2016. What's more the site metadata show

```xml
<meta name="author" content="Bundeszentrale f&uuml;r politische Bildung" />
<meta name="publisher" content="Bundeszentrale f&uuml;r politische Bildung" />
<meta name="date" content="2017-01-15" scheme="YYYY-MM-DD" />
<meta name="last-modified" content="2016-09-08" scheme="YYYY-MM-DD" />
```

and

```
    "datePublished":    "2016-09-08T00:00:00+01:00",
    "dateCreated":      "2017-01-15T22:30:16+01:00",
    "dateModified":     "2016-09-08T00:00:00+01:00",
```

where confusingly the date created (2017) is after the last modified date (2016). I'd probably go with 2016 here, but I doubt it matters a great deal.

So you'd have (note that the `.bib` entry is produced with `filecontents` in this example. This is only to make the example portable and self-contained. In a real-world document you would not have the `filecontents` environment. Your `.bib` entries would live in the `.bib` file produced by JabRef.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Misc{BZ2020,
  author       = {{Bundeszentrale für politische Bildung}},
  title        = {Fusion},
  date         = {2016},
  organization = {Bundeszentrale für politische Bildung},
  url          = {https://www.bpb.de/nachschlagen/lexika/lexikon-der-wirtschaft/19363/fusion},
  urldate      = {2020-06-04},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{BZ2020}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image: Bundeszentrale für politische Bildung, (2016), Fusion, Bundeszentrale für politische Bildung, retrieved June 4, 2020, from https://www.bpb.de/nachschlagen/lexika/lexikon-der-wirtschaft/19363/fusion]

Since this entry is just a copy of a (specialist) Duden (*Duden Wirtschaft von A bis Z: Grundlagenwissen für Schule und Studium, Beruf und Alltag. 6. Aufl. Mannheim: Bibliographisches Institut 2016.*) entry, you could of course just get that Duden from your library and cite it directly skipping the middle man (bpb).

---

In general if you want to stick with `style=apa,` and have an entry where you can't give a `date`/`year` and you still don't want "n.d.", you can add

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{pubstate}
  \field{date}
  \field{year}%legacy - no ISO8601 support
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}
```

to make `style=apa,` take `urldate` into account. **But that means you are no longer APA compliant.**

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful :)

Comment: @KatharinaKlein Glad in could help. If the answer was useful to resolve your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking on the green checkmark on the top right. That will mark the question as resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Just did that. Thanks.